Unable to do the pip install -r requirements.txt command. Fatal error in launcher. What am I doing wrong?
I am unable to do the pip install -r requirements.txt command.
What am I doing wrong? It worked before I reinstalled Python to the newest version. PIP is version 24.0.
C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\xxx>pip install -r requirements.txt

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install -r requirements.txt': Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.

Translation of the last sentence: The system can't find the file.
PATH locations are ok.

Try python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

Well, is there a requirements.txt file in the  C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\xxx directory?

@DeepSpace Yes there is.

Looks like you're running the command from the C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\xxx directory which is not the place where the requirements.txt is stored.
Just to be sure, I would suggest to use the absolute path for requirements, e.g.
>pip install -r C:\some\path\foo\bar\...\requirements.txt


What tells you that's not where the requirements.txt file is?

"Fatal error in launcher" seems like a more serious error than a simple missing requirements.txt file.
